Eloquent model update method not working through web but working through tinker in Laravel 10.45.1
I have had this problem many times now and I really wonder why this is happening.
Here is its latest occurrence:
public function updateBirthDate(Request $request)
{
    try {
        $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'birthDate' => 'required|date_format:Y-m-d',
        ]);
        $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();
        $user->profile()->update(['birth_date' => Carbon::parse($request->birthDate)->timestamp]);
        return response_success([], __FUNCTION__, __('verification.user_data_updated'));
    } catch (Exception $exception) {
        Log::error(__FUNCTION__, compact('exception'));
        return response_error(__FUNCTION__, $exception->getMessage());
    }
}

The code above didn't change 'birth_date' in database when I sent the request through Postman.
But when I ran the line below in tinker, it changed 'birth_date' in database:
$user->profile()->update(['birth_date' => Carbon::parse('1990-01-01')->timestamp]);

I suppose this is a bug in this Laravel version.

What data are you sending via PostMan? Did you get Validation errors? Did you try without $request->validate()? I can see a lot of points of failure with your code that wouldn't be there if you simply did User::where('email', 'test@test.com')->first();, then $user->profile->update([...]) in tinker. Might be worth editing your question and provide some more clarification.

@TimLewis I was sure about rest of the code but now I'm in doubt, I'm going to check those. By the way, this is not the first time I'm facing this issue, so either in all those occurrences rest of the code contained some problem which I didn't notice or update method is really problematic in this Laravel version. I'm going to test it all.

No worries! I guess I should clarify; $request->validate() can send an HTTP redirect to PostMan if the headers being sent are incorrect, User::where(...)->first() can return null, and null->profile()->update() would fail. $user->profile() is a Builder instance, not a single Profile instance, and it could simply silently fail if the User doesn't have a Profile, or update the wrong one if the User has multiple profiles (I think; I've never tried $user->profile()->update() vs $user->profile->update). That's what I meant by "many possible points of failure".

@TimLewis you may be right, I just tested, I don't know why but now it's working through Postman request and with both versions: $user->profile() and $user->profile. I am going to edit my question text now to include the whole method. As you will see, there is exception handling but there wasn't an exception in either response or log file. $user->profile() returns Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne Eloquent relationship class by the way.

Very interesting... Did you change anything on the PostMan side of things? I.e. headers and/or data being sent? I wonder if it was just failing on the $request->validate() method, although it's pretty simply validation email=test@test.com and birth_date=2024-10-10 (or similar) should have been just fine. And yeah, I expected $user->profile() and $user->profile to have been fine, especially if it's a HasOne relationship. With the full code and error handling, I don't really see any problems ‍♂️

@TimLewis Nope, I didn't change anything, I just slept on it :) I just turned the computer off an on, it's like a classical IT joke. I checked the headers on Postman yesterday but I didn't change anything. Parameters, exactly same, so I don't think it was validation error (again, I didn't get any exception). Well, I don't understand either, again it's like a joke "My code doesn't work, I don't understand why. My code works, I don't understand why". I'll be even more careful if I bump into it again.

Haha, all good; I've lost track the number of times I've slept on an issue only for it to magically resolve itself  Either way, glad it's working now, and if you run into it again, you know what to do. Cheers!

I have noticed the reason when one of my methods with update didn't work but another one worked.
The following didn't work:
$user->update([
    'confirmation_code' => random_int(100000, 999999),
    'email' => $request->email,
]);

The following worked:
$user->update([
    'mail_confirmation' => true
]);

I have missed a basic point.
The second one works because 'mail_confirmation' field is in $fillable array but first one doesn't work because 'confirmation_code' isn't in $fillable array.
Update is one of the mass assignment methods of Laravel Eloquent ORM Model. Others are fill and create: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#allowing-mass-assignment
So, all the fields must be in $fillable array unless $guarded array is set.
